# Правда ли, что новые теги в html5 не валидны, если применять их к xhtml?

Tags: xhtml, html, html5, вёрстка

То есть ради нескольких тегов человек, долго работающий в xhtml, должен полностью переходить на html5?

Конечно, меня никто не заставляет переходить, но все же интересно узнать ваше мнение на этот счет. Вопрос примитивен, но я нигде не нашел конкретного ответа.

Спасибо.

Comment: "ради нескольких тегов" сразу видно писал человек "понимающий" что такое HTML5 xD

Answer (score 2):

XHTML5 определяется на основе DOM при помощи абстрактных элементов. Как следствие возможны различные сериализации. Стандарт определяет две из них: на основе SGML - HTML5 и на основе XML - XHTML5.

Иначе говоря, если раньше XHTML и HTML - это два разных стандарта, то теперь XHTML и HTML - это две записи одного стандарта. И вообще говоря, таких записей может быть много.

Поэтому если вопрос поставлен про XHTML 2.0, то он уходит в прошлое. А если - про XHTML5, то его время только наступает.

Answer (score 1):

xhtml имеет другой стандарт, это естественно что там теги html не будут работать

Answer (score 1):

Вы должны переходить на html5 не ради новых тегов, а ради новых возможностей для семантической верстки. Сайт, нормально сверстанный на html5 будет лучше индексироваться поисковым роботом, потому что он по новым тегам будет лучше отыскивать контент, а например на рекламные блоки вставленные в специальный новый тег не будут обращать внимание. Это все может улучшить поисковую выдачу, поэтому сайты сверстанные на html5 уже сейчас получают бонус от поисковиков. Ну и плюс новая технология и новые возможности для девелопера, правда конечно не во всех браузерах.

Answer (score 1):

xhtml прекратили развивать и переходить на html5 все равно придется или навсегда зависнуть в не развивающемся xhtml.

Answer (score 0):

С точки зрения современных браузеров, любая разметка — HTML5, даже если стоит доктайп XHTML1.x. Более того, такой HTML5 [может даже быть валидным](http://habrahabr.ru/post/140155/#myth4). Поэтому валидироваться по старым схемам нет никакого практического смысла.